# IMPORTXML giving a weird result

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im using google sheet's IMPORTXML function.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.sedlabanki.is/xmltimeseries/Default.aspx?DagsFra=2023-01-04T00%3a00%3a00&DagsTil=2023-01-04T23%3a59%3a59&TimeSeriesID=4055&Type=xml";"//TimeSeriesData/Entry/Value")
```

the xml data looks like this:

```
<Group ID="9">
<Name>
<![CDATA[ Opinbert viðmiðunargengi SÍ ]]>
</Name>
<TimeSeries ID="4055">
<FameName>
<![CDATA[ USD.ISK.OVMI.S.D ]]>
</FameName>
<Name>
<![CDATA[ Bandaríkjadalur ]]>
</Name>
<Description>
<![CDATA[ Bandaríkjadalur, skráð miðgengi. ]]>
</Description>
<TimeSeriesData>
<Entry>
<Date>1/4/2023 12:00:00 AM</Date>
<Value>143.130000</Value>
</Entry>
</TimeSeriesData>
</TimeSeries>
</Group>`
```

Google sheets gives me a result of '96,23611111' when I should be getting '143.130000'

How can I troubleshoot this?

I'm looking for basic troubleshooting method's So I have no idea on where to start.

Answer (score 1):

locale was missing adding "en-US" local at the end fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).